# How to filter by date on an MDX Query?

Tags: date, filter, ssms, mdx, cube

```
SELECT    [Measures].[Transaction Count] ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY (     [Country].[Country].CHILDREN,
     [Country].[Network].CHILDREN,
     [Country].[Brand].CHILDREN,
     [Acquirer Settlement Date].[Year - Week].[Date]   ) ON ROWS FROM [Acquiring]
 WHERE (   FILTER(     [Acquirer Settlement Date].[Year - Quarter - Month].[Date].MEMBERS,     [Acquirer Settlement Date].[Year - Quarter - Month].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE > '2023-03-01'   ) )
```

I'm trying to filter by date. I want to have all date after 1st of March but the table I get back is blank. Does anyone imagine what could cause this issue?
i'm 100% that there are data in the cube

i have already changed the date format but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `null` and the range operator `:` to achieve this. An example against Adventure works:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
 ,{NULL : [Date].[Date].&[20141225]} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This returns upto and including 25 December:

[image]